# How position divs with flex layout down each other when having different heights?

Tags: html, css

I have this three divs and i'm facing a problem. There's a way to position divs with flex layout down each other when having different heights?

My `.div-1` and `.div-3` have the same `width`, there's a way to put the `.div-3` instantly down the `.div-1`?

This is my code:

```css
.container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.div1 {
      width: 80%;
      background-color: gray;
      height: 40px;
}
.div2 {
       width: 20%;
       background-color: indigo;
       height: 120px;
}
.div3 {
       width: 80%;
       background-color: red;
       display: grid;
       float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="div1">
        content div 1
      </div>

      <div class="div2">
        content div 2
      </div>

      <div class="div3">
        content div 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How i can do this?

Comment: you could wrap div1 and div3 in another subcontainer and apply another flex display with a column flex-direction, then in the main container keep a flex display with a row direction and it should do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here if that's what you want: https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/yLOKbaM

```css
.container {
      display: flex;width:100%;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.subcontainer {
  display:flex;flex-direction:column;width:80%;
}
.div1 {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: gray;
      height: 40px;
}
.div2 {
       width: 20%;
       background-color: indigo;
       height: 120px;
}
.div3 {
       width: 100%;
       background-color: red;
       display: grid;
       float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="subcontainer">
      <div class="div1">
        content div 1
      </div>

       <div class="div3">
        content div 3
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="div2">
        content div 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```